# Advanced Restclient socket implementation can not connect to Spring Websocket

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-web

I have developed a chat application by using Spring Stomp and socketjs .
I have successfully connected to the websocket over my clients but I can not connect to websocket by using Advanced Restclient -> socket implementation.

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i didnt use socketjs , i can succeed to connect over Advanced Rest Client. To connect websocket without using socketjs, you should set the allowed origins : setAllowedOrigins('*')
Also if you are using stomp without socketjs , you can succeed to open a websocket connection via  Advanced Rest Client, because stomp just a sub-protocol over websocket connection. But to receive messages over websocket, you should subscribe to STOMP queue, it is impossible with Advanced Rest Client.
 -

Answer (score 0):

Restclients  runs on http protocol. Restclients not yet understand the web socket and sock JS protocol. That is the reason your rest client didn't connected to server.